# Word Boundary Regular Expression Unless Inside HTML Tag

Tags: php, html, regex, recursion, word-boundary

I have a regular expression using word boundaries that works exceedingly well...

`~\b('.$value.')\b~i`

...save for the fact that it matches text inside HTML tags (i.e. **`title="This is blue!"`**). It's a problem because I'm doing text substitution on anything the regex matches, then making tooltips appear using those **title** tags. So, as you can imagine, it's substituting text inside the title and breaking the HTML of the tooltip. For example, what should be:

`<span class="blue" title="This is blue!">Aqua</span>`

...ends up becoming...

`<span class="blue" title="This is <span class=" blue"="">Royal Blue</span>"&gt;Aqua</span>`

My use of strip_tags didn't solve the issue; I think what I need is a better regular expression which simply will not match content ending in **`blue">`** ('blue' in this case being placeholder for any other color in the array I'm comparing it against).

Can anyone append what I need to the regular expression? Or do you have a better solution?

Comment: Better solution would be to use DOM parser instead of regex to parse and alter HTML text.

Comment: Have you looked at [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) for example? I'd suggest reading a few examples and try to work it out.

Comment: As @anubhava suggested, you can look at here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Comment: Anyway...what should be your wanted result after substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex replaces often seem like the solution but they can have a lot of ill side-effects, and not really accomplish what you want. Look into DOMDocument models instead (as some commenters have suggested).

But if you insist on using regex, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532744/regex-ignore-matches-between-script-tags) a good post on SO. It uses two passes to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Davey, resurrecting this question because apart from the Dom solution, there is a better regex solution than the one mentioned so far. It's a simple solution that requires a single step.

The general solution is

```
<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|blue
```

Here's a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qG7dS4)

Any content within `<>` tags is simply skipped. 
Content in between tags, such as blue is matched, which sounds like it fits your needs.

In the expression, replace "blue" for what you like.

**Reference**

1. [How to match pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)
2. [How to match a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Comment: This is an absolutely brilliant resolution to the issue using purely RegEx. I had no idea *SKIP existed.

Comment: Yes, it's a terrific feature, available only in Perl and PCRE (PHP, R, Delphi, N++...)

Comment: I'd love to give the answer to you for this, even after all this time, but it seems like DOM parsing is still best practice. But I love RegEx sooooo much!