# Ignore tags and javascript with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to perform a regex replacement on the HTML below.  I'm using an existing (*I didn't write it and don't really understand it*) regex pattern that ignores anything inside of an HTML tag, but I need it to also ignore anything between script tags.  The pattern is `(?<!<[^>]*)(diversity|and|inclusion)`.  The problem is that the **and** in `'playerBrandingId'` in the javascript is getting matched and ultimately replaced.  In case it matters, I'm using C#.   [You can see what I get here.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%3C%5B%5E%3E%5D*%29%28diversity%7Cand%7Cinclusion%29&i=%3Cp%3EWhen%20it%20comes%20to%20building%20more%20diverse%20and%20inclusive%20workforces%2C%20the%20sports%20industry%20is%20already%20a%20leader%2C%20but%20it%20can%20do%20much%20more.%20One%20of%20the%20ways%20SBD%2FSBJ%20is%20focusing%20on%20diversity%20and%20inclusion%20is%20by%20talking%20to%20business%20leaders%20about%20what%20the%20industry%20can%20do%20better.%20In%20our%20first%20video%20in%20the%20%26ldquo%3BSBJ%20Diversity%20and%20Inclusion%26rdquo%3B%20series%2C%20we%20hear%20from%20execs%20working%20in%20leagues%2C%20technology%2C%20recruitment%20and%20academia.%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22article-offset-block%20article-video%20article-offset-block--half%22%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22u-vr2%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20id%3D%27video-F17F523A70EB43ECAF54DF46144835B4%27%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cscript%3E%20%20%20%20var%20playerParam%20%3D%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27pcode%27%3A%20%27poeXI63BtIsR_ugBoy3Z6X8KfiMo%27%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27playerBrandingId%27%3A%20%27video-F17F523A70EB43ECAF54DF46144835B4%27%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27autoplay%27%3A%20false%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27loop%27%3A%20false%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%20%20%20%20OO.ready%28function%20%28%29%20%7B%20window.ppF17F523A70EB43ECAF54DF46144835B4%20%3D%20OO.Player.create%28%27video-F17F523A70EB43ECAF54DF46144835B4%27%2C%20%27w5cW9qZTE6qRRDqfBdi861XWJTXci9uE%27%2C%20playerParam%29%3B%20%7D%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E&o=ix)

```
<p>When it comes to building more diverse and inclusive workforces, the sports industry is already a leader, but it can do much more. One of the ways SBD/SBJ is focusing on diversity and inclusion is by talking to business leaders about what the industry can do better. In our first video in the &ldquo;SBJ Diversity and Inclusion&rdquo; series, we hear from execs working in leagues, technology, recruitment and academia.</p>
<div class="article-offset-block article-video article-offset-block--half">    
  <div class="u-vr2">
    <div id='video-F17F523A70EB43ECAF54DF46144835B4'></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  var playerParam = {
    'pcode': 'poeXI63BtIsR_ugBoy3Z6X8KfiMo',
    'playerBrandingId': 'video-F17F523A70EB43ECAF54DF46144835B4',        
    'autoplay': false,
    'loop': false
  };
  OO.ready(function () { window.ppF17F523A70EB43ECAF54DF46144835B4 = OO.Player.create('video-F17F523A70EB43ECAF54DF46144835B4', 'w5cW9qZTE6qRRDqfBdi861XWJTXci9uE', playerParam); });
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

The pattern is generated by a user's query, so the pattern could include the word `window` or `player` which would be matched in the javascript when I change the pattern to include the `\b` like so: `(?<!<[^>]*)\b(window|player|and)\b`

[Another example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%3C%5B%5E%3E%5D*%29%5Cb%28diversity%7Cand%7Cwindow%7Cplayer%29%5Cb%0D%0A&i=%3Cp%3EWhen%20it%20comes%20to%20building%20more%20diverse%20and%20inclusive%20workforces%2C%20...%20diversity%20and%20...%20Diversity%20and%20Inclusion%20...%20recruitment%20and%20academia.%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22article-offset-block%20article-video%20article-offset-block--half%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22u-vr2%22%3E%3Cdiv%20id%3D%27video-F17F523A70EB43ECAF54DF46144835B4%27%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cscript%3Evar%20playerParam%20%3D%20%7B%27pcode%27%3A%20%27poeXI63BtIsR_ugBoy3Z6X8KfiMo%27%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27playerBrandingId%27%3A%20%27video-F17F523A70EB43ECAF54DF46144835B4%27%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27autoplay%27%3A%20false%2C%27loop%27%3A%20false%7D%3BOO.ready%28function%20%28%29%20%7B%20window.ppF17F523A70EB43ECAF54DF46144835B4%20%3D%20OO.Player.create%28%27video-F17F523A70EB43ECAF54DF46144835B4%27%2C%20%27w5cW9qZTE6qRRDqfBdi861XWJTXci9uE%27%2C%20playerParam%29%3B%20%7D%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E&o=ix)

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to `(?<!<[^>]*)\b(diversity|and|inclusion)\b` The `\b` adds a test for a word boundary. forcing each word inside the  `(` and `)` to be whole words.

**EDIT:**
You are trying to parse the HTML to extract the text nodes then check them,
you should not under any circumstances try to parse HTML with a regex unless you wish to invoke [rite <sub>6</sub>6<sup>6</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) *Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn.*

Use an HTML parsing library see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063203/parsing-html-with-c-net) for some ways to do it or search for *extracting text nodes from HTML with .NET and C#*

Comment: I understand why that change works in this instance, but it doesn't technically answer the question. My example is pretty specific, but it could be more general. I'll edit the question to reflect my problem better.

Comment: Let me explain further. On my web page I want to wrap the given words with a span tag that gives the text a yellow background. I'm not looking to parse the HTML, rather just ignore HTML and JavaScript. I want to leave everything in tact except the words that should be highlighted. I'm using some existing code given to us and the author is no longer available. There is more to the code that handles this function and to be honest I don't understand it all so I don't want to have to recreate the wheel. I do understand that regex is not a solid solution, but was hoping for a quick fix.

Comment: @Kevin can you edit the question to include the existing code, it's possible to use the DOM in the web browser and a bit of javascript, or possibly some XSLT, to do this. As I said above you need to locate only text nodes in the page, which using the DOM will do and then pass them through the regex.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you cannot do what I'm trying to do with Regex according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12534165/2675770).